# Java Thread: Как правильно работать с потоками?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, собственно интересует такой вопрос, как правильно работать с потоком? Допустим, есть гуи, где кнопка вызывает класс (допустим, sql) в другом потоке, как будет правильнее: при каждом нажатии кнопки вызывать новый поток и новый sql экземпляр, или создать поток и экземпляр sql 1 раз и вызывать уже метод?

Comment: Экземпляр `SQL` - это некоторый долгоживущий объект или `unit of work`? Как у его методов обстоит дело с `reentrancy`?

Comment: reentrancy - правильно ли я понимаю - это потокобезопасность? Сейчас переосмыслил выше описанный вопрос, по сути поток будит жить постоянно пока не вывозишь interrupt, по соображениям ресурсоемкости поток с sql как и сам экземпляр должен быть вызван 1 раз, направлю вопрос в другую сторону ибо не нашел хорошего примера, как обратится к объекту из другого потока, потокобезопастность не требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

threadpoolexecutor

Comment: ExecutorService